# sum number of a string of a cell that meet certain conditions

Tags: excel, vba, sum, conditional-statements

I just wonder how to calculate this in vba:
Calculate the first amount of money if it is yes but not calculate the amount if it is no. Imagine there are four cells:

```
(cell 1) abcbc bcbcbcb cbcbcbc $1000/kskskksks/$2000//1222/1221/11/yes  
(cell 2) any words will be here $2300/heyhey hey/ //3232//3232/no  
(cell 3) kakjsak  dsdsk kdjskj 2323/ $23232/hhehe 22/33/333/yes  
(cell 4) kakaka kjsdkj ksjskjds kdjsjkdj 11 223 222/ $1121/ $2121/yes
```

The algorithm is to check whether is yes or no. Then, on each line, find the first money, beginning with $, the second money on the same line would not take into account.

In this example, the program will take `$1000` into account, because it is yes, second line would not be executed since it is no. And the third cell would take the first money (first $), `$23232`. So, the program will sum `$1000+$23232+$1121=$25353`

Comment: It looks like you are importing a text file in a wrong way: instead of having different columns every piece of information is within one cell. Did you try to import your data using the text import wizard?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that this is what you want, considering that you are using the first column to place each value and your sheet's name is "Sheet1"

```
Sub SumFirstAmountIfYes()

    Dim AmountSum As Variant ' Declares the AmountSum

    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Finds the last used row on the first column

    For i = 1 To lastRow ' Iterates over the rows to the last row
        StringValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value2 ' Gets the value to a variable
        If StringValue Like "*yes" Then ' Checks if the string terminates with "yes"
            FirstDollar = InStr(StringValue, "$") ' Finds first dollar symbol "$"
            FirstSlashAfterDollar = InStr(FirstDollar, StringValue, "/", 0) ' Finds first slash "\" after the first dollar symbol

            FirstAmount = Mid(StringValue, FirstDollar + 1, FirstSlashAfterDollar - FirstDollar - 1) ' Gets the amount of each row

            AmountSum = AmountSum + CDec(FirstAmount) ' Adds to the sum variable each found amount
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox (AmountSum) ' Shows the final sum of the amounts

End Sub
```

Comment: well actually, it works well but when the symbol "$" is replaced to another symbol such as "AUD", it won't work. How to figure it out? and sometimes, the "yes" could be anywhere in the line (beginning, middle, or the end).

Comment: About the "yes": instead of using `If StringValue Like "*yes"`, use `If StringValue Like "*yes*"`, with the asterisk in the beginning and in the end of the string.

Comment: About the "$"... well. You could search for the character position of each symbol, such as "$", "AUD", "BTC", etc... and use the one with smaller index.

Answer (score 0):

This uses split to isolate yes/no and InStr to locate the  first currency symbol.

```
Sub sumYes()
    Dim i As Long, str As String, dbl As Double

    With Worksheets("Sheet10")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            str = LCase(.Cells(i, "A").Value2)
            If Split(str, "/")(UBound(Split(str, "/"))) = "yes" Then
                If CBool(InStr(1, str, Chr(36))) Then
                    dbl = dbl + Val(Mid(str, InStr(1, str, Chr(36)) + 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        .Cells(2, "B") = dbl
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach which uses excel array formula assuming your cell values doesn't contain trailing spaces ,

[image]

```
=SUM(IF(RIGHT(A1:A4,1)="s",MID(A1:A4,SEARCH("$",A1:A4)+1,SEARCH("/",A1:A4,SEARCH("$",A1:A4))-SEARCH("$",A1:A4)-1)*1,""))
```